# A basic schema for a trading situation

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design, schema

What's a basic database schema for trading items?  Here are the rules for the trade:

1. users propose a trade for other user's items.
2. both users can counter each other's proposals as many times.

Its very brief and general but I'm just looking for a basic schema to help me in the right direction in designing the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you're talking about bidding (auctions) ... here is a decent schema  I have loosely used in the past for such projects.

http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/auction/index.htm